# How to rebuild the 'indexing' package on MAC OSX

Tags: r, macos, indexing, r-forge

I am trying to install 'indexing' package in r: [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=648)

However, It says it is "failed to build" & am looking for a way to fix this? I do not see a download option for the package.... I am currently on MAC OSX Yosemite and trying to load this in the latest R-Studio.

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

When trying to load via r-studio:

```
install.packages("indexing", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
> source repository is unavailable to check versions
> Error in install.packages : Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
```

Comment: Could you share the log output and the error message?

Comment: @Pascal I have updated my code,

Comment: According to the page you linked, the build status is "Failed to build".

Comment: @pascal yeah i mentioned that, but i am trying to find a way to fix it if possible, & could not find any mirrors

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake. This package is not distributed through CRAN. And according to the same page, build is successful until R version 3.0.0. For more recent version, as yours, it fails. And as you mentioned, there is not access to the source. So, I guess there is no solution to build this package.

Comment: @pascal I see, However I did find the following describing on rebuilding  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Indexing-Package-td4594298.html

Comment: Yes, me too. But as the download link was frozen in-between, you cannot access the source of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the download link on R-forge doesn't appear to work any more (it may say not available for version >= 3.3. etc), you can still install indexing from source on OSX (or any other operating system).

Open a new terminal in OS X, and in a directly of your choice type the following to install `indexing`:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/indexing/
```

If you did this correctly, type `ls` in the terminal and you should see a new directory called `indexing`.  Inside this directory is the source code you need to build the `indexing` package.

Without changing from the current directory, install the dependency R package `mmap` if you don't already have it (you might have already installed in from CRAN, in which case you may be able to skip this step) with:

```
R CMD INSTALL indexing/pkg/mmap
```

Finally, install indexing from source

```
R CMD INSTALL indexing/pkg/indexing
```

You should see something like this in the terminal output if successful:

```
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘indexing’ ...
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/indexing/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (indexing)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: where have you been this past 1 year & 8 months!? lol thank you it worked @FXQuantTrader